# Use own file extension in streamlit's file_uploader

Tags: python, file-upload, streamlit, suffix

[Streamlit's file_uploader widget](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.file_uploader) let's you define the allowed file extensions via the `type` option:

> type (str or list of str or None)
>
> Array of allowed extensions. ['png', 'jpg'] The default is None, which
> means all extensions are allowed.

In contrast to the common file extensions I am working with a non-standard one like `.details.txt`. These files can be selected if `type='txt` is configured:

```
uploaded_files = st.file_uploader(
    "Choose file(s)",
    type=['txt'],
    accept_multiple_files=True,
)
```

However, this also allows the user to provide other `txt` files which I want to prevent. The user should be able to upload `.details.txt` files only, but not files like `.report.txt`.

Specifying `type='.details.txt'` or `type='details.txt'` did not do the trick. In these cases I was not able to select any file.

The following snippet can be used to reproduce the behavior described:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import streamlit as st

uploaded_files = st.file_uploader(
    "Choose file(s)",
    type=['txt'],
    # type=['.txt'],
    # type=['details.txt'],
    # type=['.details.txt'],
    accept_multiple_files=True,
)
```

In addition, you would need to create a `something.txt` and a `something.details.txt` file on your filesystem.

Is there a way to specify own non-standard file types?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me in Streamlit, version 1.6.0.

```
type=['.details.txt'],
```